# Create option for each file

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class = "Top">
<center>
<h1>
Reaper MP3
</h1>
</center>
</div>

<div class = "Middle">
<center>
<input type = "file" webkitdirectory id = "In" oninput = "LoadFiles()" value = "">

<br>

<select id = "Sel" class = "S">
</select>
</center>
</div>

<div class = "Bottom">
<center>
<audio controls src = "" id = "Plyr">
</audio>
</center>
</div>

<style>
.Top {
width: 100%; height: 50px;
background: #FF0000;
}

.Middle {
width: 100%; height: 500px;
background: #990099;
}

.S {
width: 150px; height: 25px;
}

.Bottom {
width: 100%; height: 50px;
background: #FF0000;
}
</style>

<script>
var SelectFolder = document.getElementById("In");

var Player = document.getElementById("Plyr");
var Select = document.getElementById("Sel");

var DefaultFolder = "/This PC/Music";
var NewOption = document.createElement("option");
var Info = document.createTextNode("");
NewOption.appendChild(Info);

Select.appendChild(NewOption);

function LoadFiles() {

}
</script>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get it to where I can add a option to select for each file in a folder. In my case the folder's path is "/This PC/Music" and then have it to where the audio src = the selected file/option. does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can't normally read from a folder on disk. if the folders are on your server, you need some server-side language (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET/C#) to look through the folders and create the HTML markup for you. Or have a webservice that returns the list to your javascript (via Ajax) and then the javascript builds it - but that seems unnecessary in this case, unless there's more to it

Answer (score 0):

As **ADyson** pointed out javascript is running on the client side so you can't access the files. However you can do this with php (it's server-side) and I'll show you how:

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
    <?php
       $dir_handle=opendir("directory_path_here");  //creates a handle of the dir
       while (false!==($file=readdir($dir_handle))) { //loop through files/folders in the dir
          echo( "<input type='checkbox' name='items[]' value='$file' />");    //show it on page after load
       }

    ?>


    </body>


</html>
```

Those are checkboxes. I see you have a select in your code and you can use that too. After the user selects something you can use ajax with jQuery to play the music or refresh the page sending the selected music to itself (in a form with get or post).